# Can CA public benefit corps be for-profit?

Tags: california, corporate-law

I'm interested in forming a public benefit corporation in California in 2018. As I understand it, these can be for-profit. But when I look at the California government [website](http://www.sos.ca.gov/business-programs/business-entities/filing-tips/filing-tips-corp/) for information about filing Articles of Incorporation, it implies that public benefit corporations must file as not-for-profit.

A different source seemed to say it was enough to state “this is a public benefit corporation” in the Articles of Incorporation (in addition to all the requirements of a B Corp).

How do I incorporate a for-profit B corp in California?

Comment: Can you provide your (different) source, and include the relevant verbiage within the question?

Comment: California law seems to identify "public benefit corporation" as a type of non-profit corporation, not a business corporation (for private benefit).

Comment: Hence my question.